# How to hide row group by level

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I use Ag grid for showing some data on table.
So, we have **columnDef**

```js
const columnDef = [
        {
            field: 'colorName',
            rowGroup: true,
            hide: true,
            ....another props (renderer etc.)
        },
        {
            field: 'color',
            rowGroup: true,
            hide: true,
             ....another props (renderer etc.)
        },
        {
            field: 'titleName',
            rowGroup: true,
            hide: true,
             ....another props (renderer etc.)
        },
]

As you see, I try to group and hide the main 3 field in columnDefs.
```

We have some row data:

```js
const rowData = [
         {
        name: 'Name 1',
        titleName: 'Label',
        colorName: 'Color 1',
        color: '#FCE300',
    },
    {
        name: 'Name 1-1',
        titleName: 'Label',
        productName: 'Color 1',
        color: '#FCE300',
    },
    {
        name: 'Name 2',
        titleName: 'Label',
        colorName: 'Color 1',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    {
        name: 'Name 3',
        titleName: 'Label',
        colorName: 'Color 2',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
    },
]
```

The result is:

[image]

Question is: How I can leave **group data by this 3 fields** (colorName, color, titleName) but **hide one level group rows** from view. For example I need to hide **color** group row, but leave the grouping data by all 3 main fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think `rowGroup` doens't allow to do this.
I suggest you to use [TreeData](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/tree-data/). More complex a bit but give a full customizations for showing data